# money rails gem, how to save 6 decimal to field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency, money-rails

I have field

```
monetize :unit_price_cents, as: 'unit_price', with_model_currency: :unit_price_currency
```

It's type in database is float. And I want to save value in database keep 6 decimal value. in Money GEM, I custom success:

```
Money.new(1.123456).to_f => 0.01123456
```

I debug some func, and think the problem in gem money-rails. It round before calling Money.new

So any config or customize could do that? code loading in gem so crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for allowing to use decimal cents. Just add config to initialize/money.rb

```
Money.infinite_precision = true
```

and maybe you want to customize func format of Money gem to show decimal for cent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question. 
Can you change the database format to decimal(12,6)? This allows for 6 digits BEFORE the decimal point, which should be enough for everybody(tm)